# When does it make sense to use a public package as a Submodule in Python vs installing using pip?

Tags: python, git

I am working on a python project that has many open sourced dependencies that may not be regularly maintained. I tried using packages as submodules by adding them with Git; but then I get an error saying the module I want is not available when I try to use the submodule; when I install the package with pip it works fine. This hasn't happened with every package. I am wondering why I can't use the submodule like I would the installed package simply by importing it?

(Modules seem to be missing from the submodule import vs the pip package installed import.)

However is it better to use these packages as submodules or just add the required package and version number to a requirements.txt file to be installed for production deployment?

(Any additional functionality required for a submodule or package is added with a wrapper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess your issue is that git is putting the submodule side by side to your project, and Python "can't import above top level" issue applies there. Either way, you don't really want a submodule in the git sense, you want the module to be installed into site-packages for your python environment / virtual env.

I would stick to using pip since it is a python-specific tool & makes more sense as a workflow than using a git submodule for this usage. You can point pip at git repositories too, just make sure the ssh key is installed. For example:

```sh
pip install --upgrade "git+ssh://git@https://repo_url.git@branchname
```

Also, try Pipenv if you haven't? It works great when writing out deployment manifests.

Answer (score 12):

`git` is a development tool; you use it during development but not deployment. `pip` is a deployment tool; during development you use it to install necessary libraries; during deployment your users use it to install your package with dependencies.

Use submodules when you need something from a remote repository in your development environment. For example, if said remote repository contains Makefile(s) or other non-python files that you need and that usually aren't installed with `pip`.

For everything else `pip` is preferable.