# Git submodule's local import error - Python

Tags: python, git, importerror, git-submodules

I'm working on a Python project (*Project A*) that uses another project from GitHub (*Project B*). I'm not a Git expert, so after a quick research, I found out that I should use the *Project B* as a `git submodule`.

So, I `cd project_A_root` and did the following:

```
git submodule add project_B
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Now, my project structure looks like this:
[image]

In *main.py* file, I've imported a method from *do_something.py*.

***main.py***

```
from ProjectB.do_something import foo
```

However, *do_something.py* file imports a method from *util.py* file, and that's where the problem occurs.

***do_something.py***

```
from util import bar
```

*Project B* is a submodule and it assumes that *Project B* dir is the root of the project, so method from *util.py* in *do_something.py* is imported without specifying the package, and I'm getting an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'util'
```

Instead, it should be imported like this:

```
from ProjectB.util import bar
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to handle this.
I've fixed imports in submodule manually, but I cannot push that changes to Git because that's not how the submodules work, so if anyone wants to clone *Project A*, they must fix imports manually too.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: "*…I found out that I should use the Project B as a git submodule.*" No, you shouldn't. You should use a proper dependency/package management. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54155860/7976758

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the head of `main.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("ProjectB")

#### your old code ###
....
```

Comment: I saw that solution with `sys.path.append`, but at first I've added that to `do_something.py`... It works when I add that to `main.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Git is just a version control system. Unfortunately, you can't handle this correctly.
The possible solution is patching `sys.path` variable by adding the *ProjectB* directory, but this is hack.
The best you can do is to use a Python packaging system, to package ProjectB into a pip package and install it as a usual package by pip.
Usefull links:

- https://packaging.python.org/
- https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html
- https://python-poetry.org/

Answer (score 1):

ProjectB should have an `__init__.py` file in its top-level directory. Having one would mean it would be recognised as a package, and the files within ProjectB could import other files from within ProjectB.

`do_something.py` would be able to import util by using:

`from .util import bar`

The `.` before `util` is interpreted to mean "from the top-level of this package", and because there's a `__init__.py` file in the ProjectB directory, Python would know that that's the top-level folder being referred to. This means that whatever you named the ProjectB directory, or where you moved it, the files inside it would not need to change their import statements.

You'd still import `foo` from `main` by doing

`from ProjectB.do_something import foo`.

If you can edit ProjectB or raise an issue with the developers of ProjectB, they may be able to add this for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to summarize this approach, which doesn't require changing the system path:  
(1) all code imports local to a submodule should be relative, (2) all modules using submodules can continue using absolute imports.

Comment: Does this work differently between python 2.7 and 3.8? I'm working on some old code and I'm trying to figure out why this fix works me (and why the old code doesn't appear to need this fix)