# Why css can not load in React but only in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

We have a component, which is in a Git Submodule, because a NExt.js and a React is using it also. In NextJs everything ok, but fro React, it does not accept how CSS is loaded:

```
import styles from "../../styles/buyTicket.module.css";
```

```
[tsl] ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx(7,20)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '../../styles/buyTicket.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.
 @ ./app/containers/Tiket/Test.tsx 2:0-148 36:88-133
 @ ./app/containers/Test.jsx 3:0-32 6:44-48
 @ ./app/shortcode35.js 8:0-46 14:54-63
```

What is wrong here? css is at the right place

Comment: Are other relative imports working? Do you think it can be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185563/git-submodules-local-import-error-python ? (even thought the question is in python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you simply import it as 
`import "../../styles/buyTicket.module.css";`

Then in your element className is defined like vanilla html
`<div className="class"></div>`

Comment: PS `.module` part isn't necessary in React

Comment: you are right, would you check this here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692708/how-to-use-css-modules-in-a-react-based-wordpress-plugin

Comment: @János seems like you have a answer already there