# How to use CSS modules in a React based Wordpress plugin?

Tags: css, reactjs, wordpress, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have this line in one of my `tsx` file:

```
import styles from "../../styles/buyTicket.module.css";
```

got this error:

```
ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx
./tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx 7:19-54
[tsl] ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx(7,20)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '../../styles/buyTicket.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

If I remove `styles` then I got this error no more, but then it will work not as a CSS module, and naming collosion will happen. What would you suggest?

Comment: have you tried just importing it like so: `import "../../styles/buyTicket.module.css";`?

Comment: Yes, it works then, but then it will work not as a CSS module, and naming collosion will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can understand, you may have a look here:
[Can't import CSS/SCSS modules. TypeScript says "Cannot Find Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module)

and here:
[React, Typescript - Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/react-typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declaration/65147812)